# C# Access is Denied when adding user to Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

```
string strName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // "MW\\dalem"
        string domainName = strName.Split('\\')[0];
        using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
            {
                using (var user = new UserPrincipal(pc, Admin-Username, Admin-Pass, true))
                {
                    fullname = fname + " " + lname;
                    user.SamAccountName = username;
                    user.SetPassword(password);
                    user.GivenName = fname;
                    user.Surname = lname;
                    user.DisplayName = fullname;
                    user.Save();
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to add the user to active directory, I get the error saying

> "Access is Denied"

at the `user.Save();` line. I don't understand why since I have full admin rights. This is my third or 5th approach at trying to add a user to the active directory.

Comment: Is Visual studio in Administrator mode?

Comment: It wasn't but now that I've opened it in administrator mode, I'm getting error message saying "The object already exists" but i don't see it in the Active directory users

Comment: Can't you just use `NULL` for the domain name to get the domain you're currently connected to?

Comment: The problem was that visual studio wasn't on administrator mode as spiderman pointed out. reason it said "the object already exists" but i couldn't see the user in user list was because I forgot to enable the account. It was there, it just wasn't activated.

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve this by saving the database context:

```
string strName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // "MW\\dalem"
        string domainName = strName.Split('\\')[0];
        using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
            {
                using (var user = new UserPrincipal(pc, Admin-Username, Admin-Pass, true))
                {
                    fullname = fname + " " + lname;
                    user.SamAccountName = username;
                    user.SetPassword(password);
                    user.GivenName = fname;
                    user.Surname = lname;
                    user.DisplayName = fullname;
                    userPrincipal.Add(user);
                }
            pc.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: principal context doesn't have that method

Comment: is the context of the type- Entity Data Model(edmx)?

Comment: umm idk about that, since i am new to this stuff, but pc.Savechanges(); is underlined and when I hover the mouse on it, it says "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext does not contain the defination of "SaveChanges" and no extentions method 'SaveChanges' first agrugment of type.. and so on"